# PMSE Earns its Yearling Badge

Tags: discussion

We should all take a step back and wish Project Management Stack Exchange a belated happy birthday.  On February 7th, PMSE gained the required number of committers in Area 51 to graduate it to beta site status.

A year later, the site has helped answer over 800 questions that have helped not only the people who have askes the questions, but also it's helped all of us that have had an opportunity to learn from the experiences of the professionals and enthusiasts on this site.

We didn't plan any celebrations, but I thought perhaps we could take a moment to highlight this milestone by posting links to our favorite questions that have been posted on this site.

- What is *your* all time favorite question that was posted on PMSE over the past year, and what value did the question bring to you or our site?
- Who else could benefit from the questions?  How could you get that information out to people who could benefit from this knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/19/what-is-the-project-management-book-that-left-the-most-impact-on-you) question was my favorite. I ordered several of the books suggested in the replies, and was not disappointed.

As for getting the information out, I have PMSE on my LinkedIn profile and I tweet posts that I like every so often. I think that promoting an official LinkedIn group and Twitter feed would be helpful at exposing the site to people who might benefit.

Comment: This topic was the first one that came to my mind when thinking of the best question on PMSE. I might receive two of these books in a couple of months and I'm looking forward to vote up on the answers!